# GWT FocusProblems

Tags: gwt, focus, tabindex

How can I set the focus to the next tab index?

I have a form, that contains several widget and I would like to handler the tab key down, to set the focus from A widget to B

Comment: Thanks I fixed this problem with another way :)

Comment: Which way? :) it can be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> setTabIndex(int);

method to set the focus from widget A to widget B.